# What is this plant with long skinny leaves with red margins?

Tags: identification

I got the plant in the picture:

[image]

Which plant is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's Dracaena marginata

I have one in my garden, I cut it off at ground level because it was in the way for painting the house. It grew back. The bits I cut off got thrown in an old broken bucket with some crappy dirt in a place that gets a bit of sun and they're still alive 5 years later. Basically if it is what I think it is then it's tough as old boots and looks pretty decent in the process. Cut it back if it gets too long and leggy.

Comment: One of the **Tricolor** variants: https://www.google.com/search?q=Dracaena+marginata+tricolor&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje8Ki91J_LAhVDrD4KHUxcA2MQ_AUIBygB&biw=1036&bih=519